# Run spring boot project on xampp htdocs folder

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, xampp, localhost

I made a spring boot project with Maven.
I moved it to another pc where I have already downloaded Xampp and create a db in PHPMyAdmin.
I want to move in htdocs folder on Xampp so it can always run once clicked localhost on the browser.
Can anyone please explain to me how to achieve that please?

At the moment my project path is  this C:\xampp\htdocs\myprojectFolder
if I click on the browser comes up this kind of weird show of the folder of the project:

[image: kind of weird show of the folder of the project]

Navigate through my html page gives error 404.

Comment: What makes you think that would work? XAMPP is for PHP, you are running Java.

Comment: i did the whole spring boot project running on xamp with apache and mysql connected.

Comment: No you didn't, you aren't running anything, you only dropped some files in there. That is simply not how it works. It doesn't run on XAMP, it can use the MySQL instance, and you can use the Apache HTTP server as a front end proxy but that is it. It will not run your java application.

Comment: From the XAMPP website "XAMPP is an easy to install Apache distribution containing MariaDB, PHP, and Perl."

Java applications needs JVM to run a Java project.

You should be able to run your Spring Boot application following the official latest documentation available.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html#getting-started.first-application

Comment: thanks @Marcelo i ve done that to develop the program already.

Comment: thanks @M.Deinum i understand your point. i apologize im quite newbies in this field.I will explain more detail and if you can please give me any advise on how to solve my issues.   
 i develop my project with spring boot thymeleaf mysql on my pc.Now i want to pass on another pc,do i need to donwload eclipse to run the project every time or there is other solution so it will always run localhost on the browser ???

Comment: Eclipse is an IDE (your development environment). If you want to run it you need to create an artifact (the jar) which you can run. If that other PC is also for development you can just use `mvnw spring-boot:run` to run the application without an IDE. But if you want to develop on it an IDE is quite handy.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time.I just need to pass my project on the pc(not for development) so anyone can use through vpn or dpr.Obviusly i want to achieve same process  as xamp so they dont need to run the project from an ide.So in order that xamp is not usable for java app ,the pther pc is not development i need to find out how can achieve that in a easiest way as possible please.